# how can add database data to dropdown list using angular js in php

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova

hey iam working on phonegap, and i want to list my table data into a drop down,
i tried ,but i couldn't make that.
iam not familiar with angular js. iam using php for retrieving data.Here i want to list my city details(id,name) in to a dropdown. pls help me

```
      <body ng-app="sign" ng-controller="signCtrl">   
                            <div class="ui-field-contain">  
                    <select data-theme="a"  name="cityname" id="cityname" ng-model="cityname" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in city" /> </select>
                </div>
```

**js**

```
    var app = angular.module('sign', []);
  app.controller('signCtrl', function ($scope, $http,$window) {

 $scope.cityname = null;
 $scope.city = [];
 var submitUrl = base_url+"login/getData";
 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: submitUrl,
    data: {}
 }).success(function (result) {
    alert(result.regData.cityList);
      //$scope.city = result;
  });
});
```

**controller**

```
    public function getData(){
        $city_list=$this->LM->city_list(); 
        $lang_list=$this->LM->getLang();  
        echo '{"regData":{"cityList":'.json_encode($city_list->result_array()).',"langList":'.json_encode($lang_list->result_array()).'}}';   
    }
```

**model**

```
              public function city_list()
    {
        $this->db->select('city_id,city_name');
        $this->db->from('city'); 
        $query= $this->db->get(); 
        return $query;         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the cause?

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: submitUrl,
        data: {}
     }).success(function (result) {
        alert(result.regData.cityList);
          //$scope.city = result;

          //TRY this:
          $scope.city = result.regData.cityList;
      });
```

You did not assign `city` to any value ...

Comment: Sorry, probably should be this: `$scope.city = result.regData.cityList`